# How to adapt input_shape parameter to table dimensions in R

Tags: r, dataframe, keras, input, neural-network

[image][image]So far, I have a net looking like this:

```
data <- data2018

# Splitting data into train and test
set.seed(101)
sample <- sample.int(n = nrow(data), size = floor(.75 * nrow(data)), replace = F)
train <- as.data.table(data[sample, ])
test <- as.data.table(data[-sample, ])

# Preparing the training set
cols <- c(names(train))
train %<>% mutate_at(cols, as.factor)
train %<>% mutate_at(cols, as.numeric)
train %<>% mutate_at(cols,~(scale(.) %>% as.vector))
train[is.na(train) ] <- 0

# Splitting train into x (parameters) and y (prediction values)
x_train <- data.matrix(train[,-"1"])
y_train <- data.matrix(train[, "1"])

# Designing model
model <- keras_model_sequential() %>%
layer_dense(units = 128, activation = 'tanh', input_shape = dim(x_train)[-1]) %>%
layer_dropout(rate = 0.4) %>%
layer_dense(units = 64, activation = 'tanh') %>%
layer_dropout(rate = 0.3) %>%
layer_dense(units = 32, activation = 'tanh') %>%
layer_dropout(rate = 0.2) %>%
layer_dense(units = 16, activation = 'tanh') %>%
layer_dropout(rate = 0.1) %>%
layer_dense(units = length(unique(data$`1`)), activation = 'softmax')

# Summarize model layers and units
summary(model)

# Compile model
model %>% compile(
loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',
optimizer = optimizer_rmsprop(),
metrics = c('accuracy')
)

# Train model
history <- model %>% fit(
x_train, y_train,
epochs = 100, batch_size = 32,
validation_split = 0.2
)
```

Due to secrecy issues, I cannot show the original datatable but it is a simple table consisting of 7 rows and 34 columns (only a small simulation chunk).

The input (x_train) is already normalized and vectorized. It is a simple table with rows and columns.

```
dim(x_train)
```

Result:

```
> dim(x_train)
[1]  5 33
```

However, if I try to train the model, keras prints out this cryptic error message.

```
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
ValueError: in user code:

/home/seschlbeck/.local/share/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.6/site-   packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:855 train_function  *
    return step_function(self, iterator)
/home/seschlbeck/.local/share/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:845 step_function  **
    outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
/home/seschlbeck/.local/share/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1285 run
    return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
/home/seschlbeck/.local/share/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2833 call_for_each_replica
    return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
/home/seschlbeck/.local/share/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3
```

This has something to do with my input shape, I guess. But I just can't figure out why...
I have already tried out the following ones (all not working)

```
dim(x_train)
c(5, 33)
c(None, 5, 33)
dim(x_train)[1]
```

Does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong here? Any help is appreciated...

Comment: So you could not show the original data. Have you considered offering toy data to those who want to try out their putative answers before posting them?

Comment: I just added pictures of both the original table and x_train (vectorized).

Answer (score 0):

The `input_shape` should be fine. This kind of error message occurs when the number of units in the "output" layer is misspecified. There are likely just two categories in your training sample, i.e., binary classification but your code is for the `n`-class case where you need `n` units and categorical cross-entropy loss. Try setting a *single* unit in the last dense layer:

```
layer_dense(units = 1, activation = 'softmax')
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately, I need as many output neurons as I have different values in that column. Each code in that column stands for a specific disease and I want to give a percentage between 0 and 1 about how likely this disease is for that person...

Comment: I see. Still, think that this relates to the number of categories: as I understand, your training data has 5 rows of which 2 are used for validation, which sounds like trouble if you have more than two categories. For better help, we need some mock data that allows reproducing the error.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still haven't figured it out yet but the bounty is yours for steering my attention to the output layer also...